# I have one batch class which updates Account Name to true. But Not getting updated data in Test class inside System.assertEquals()

Tags: unit-test

```
public class CustomIterator
  implements Iterator<Account>{ 

  private List<Account> accs;
  private List<Contact> conts;
  private Integer currentIndex;

  public CustomIterator(List<Account> accs){
      this.accs = accs;
      this.currentIndex = 0;
  }
 
  public boolean hasNext(){ 
      return currentIndex < accs.size() - 1;
  }    

  public Account next(){
      if(hasNext()) {
          currentIndex++;
          return accs[currentIndex];
      } else {
          throw new NoSuchElementException();
      }
  } 
}
```

```
public class CustomIterable implements Iterable<Account> {
   public Iterator<Account> iterator(){
      List<Account> accs =
      [SELECT Id, Name, Rating
       FROM Account
       LIMIT 10 ];
      return new CustomIterator(accs);
   } 
  }
```

```
global class BatchClass implements Database.Batchable<Account>{
    
   global Iterable<Account> start(Database.BatchableContext info){
       return new CustomIterable();
   }
   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<Account> scope){
       List<Account> accsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
       for(Account acc : scope){
           acc.Name = 'true';
           accsToUpdate.add(acc);
       }
       update accsToUpdate;
   }
   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info){
       System.debug('Batch Done');
   }
}
```

```
@isTest
public class BatchClassTest {

    @testSetup
    public static void makeData(){
            Account acc=new Account(Name='Test Account');
            insert acc;
    }

    @isTest
    public static void batchTest(){
        BatchClass obj=new BatchClass();
        Test.startTest();
        Id jobId=Database.executeBatch(obj);
        Test.stopTest();
        Account accAfterUpdate=[Select id, Name From Account];
       System.assertEquals('true', accAfterUpdate.Name);
        
    }
}
```

```
Getting Below Error While Executing Test class.
//System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: true, Actual: Test Account
```

Answer (score 1):

Your unit test found a bug. By writing more granular unit tests to evaluate each piece of functionality in your code, you might have been able to get more direct guidance to the source of the problem:

```
  public boolean hasNext(){ 
      return currentIndex < accs.size() - 1;
  }
```

The logic here is incorrect. Assume `accs.size()` is 1 (as it is in your test context). Your iterator will never return `true` to `hasNext()` and will therefore stop immediately.

Comment: thanks got the point ....but this code is from the apex developer guide only..I copied that code from the apex library and tried to write a test class.

Comment: Hah, you found a bug in the documentation, I think! I will file it with the documentation team. You could solve it by setting `currentIndex = -1` in the constructor.

Comment: Yea I solved it from documentation only... got the answer from Spring 20(Api Version 50) apex guide. The Latest Version Summer 22 (Api Version 55) has a bug in code...please check and report it.